# Can I put a script at the bottom of a web page, but call it from the top?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Could this cause potential problems:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
      ...
      <INPUT name="xyz" onchange="myFunction();">
      ...
     <SCRIPT>
        function myFunction()
        {
          ...
        }
      </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

What happens if the page loads slowly and the form renders before the script portion at the bottom is loaded?  Will a JavaScript error occur if the user enters some text into the INPUT box?

Comment: Quite simply - yes.  Why do you want to do this, anyway?

Comment: @Andrzej: Lots of JavaScript performance guidelines advise loading scripts at the bottom of the page when possible (e.g. the [Yahoo performance rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)) so there’s a lot of incentive of doing that.

Comment: Just by looking at this small snippet of code, she has way more issues than loading scripts at the end of the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the script before you can call it. Why don't you change it to something like this:

```
<input name="xyz" id="myInput">
      ...
     <script>
        function myFunction
        {
          ...
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
            myInput.onchange = myFunction;
        }
      </script>
```

This approach allows you to separate your markup and scripting and have all of your js in one place.

Answer (score 1):

It works, though it may be a problem if you loaded more HTML and it took longer for the browser to parse your JavaScript at the end. In that case, your function won't be defined and you will get...

> myFunction() is not defined

Note you need to add open and closing parenthesis (`(` & `)`) after `myFunction`.

Whilst functions declarations are hoisted, they are only hoisted in their containing script block.

Also, you should really use lowercase tags, it isn't 1998 anymore :) And a doctype also helps, and finally, you should try and remove your event handlers from inline attributes.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript development has changed over the years.

Not only is your original question being debated, but to go back to the theme of your original question, so is your methodology itself.

I highly recommend reading this short bit on some JavaScript best practices:
http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/best-practices-for-modern-javascript-development.

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to be defined in the DOM prior to it being executed.  If script is at the bottom it needs to be loaded prior to use.